# Anyway to call a c# method after complete (callback) ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms, callback

I am writing some javascript methods which needs to call from c# code. after complete of JS methods I need to a C# code to send email.

How to do that?

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "newPasswordGen", 
      "GenerateTempPassword();", true);
```

Comment: If you want to call some server side code from client side code  then you will have to create a web service or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call c# from JavaScript You can either create an [ASMX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359) web service (becoming deprecated) or preferably a [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb924552%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) web service.

Also, you can use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) for real-time scenarios.